# How to convert a PublicKey to JSON in Java?

Tags: java, json, rsa

I want to send a client's public key (java.security.publickey) in JSON format to my server. I'm using Google's Gson library to convert in between, however, I'm getting a runtime exception which tells me that Key is an interface and I need some kind of adapter to parse it. Have anyone encountered this problem? Any solution is welcome, I just need to transfer the key via HTTP.

Thank you!

Comment: Create a data structure that is mean't to be serialized to JSON and deserialized from JSON. Then, on the client, transform your key to this data structure, and on the server, recreate a key from the information in this data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the encoded key using the getEncoded() method and send that via JSON to your server.